# Change how variables look in debugger, vb.net 2003

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I've been given an old VB.net 1.1, Visual Studio 2003, project.
When debugging DateTime shows as #09:34:00 AM#, the date-part is hidden. I would like to see which date the DateTime is.

I've tried to modify mcee_cs.dat, but that doesn't seem to do anything.
Is there some other file I should modify to get my desired behavior?

/L

Comment: Ok. Just realized that is only TimeOfDay is displayed, that means Date isn't set.
However, I would still like to be able to configure how a DateTime looks in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a watch for a custom expression. OK, simple enough: add a watch for the following expression:

```
YourDateVariable.ToString("CustomFormatString")
```

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for custom format strings.

Comment: That means I have to make explicit "watch" for all things I would like to see, right?
Would work, but if I can change the default behavior I would have to do less when looking. 
/Lazy